# Python could not identify class in module without parantheses

Tags: python

I just had an odd behavior in python which was that I defined a class in a module, and I tried to import it but the interpreter could not find the class.

```
# src/AudioBuffer.py
class AudioBuffer:
```

This could not be imported in a different file as

```
# src/Recorder.py
from AudioBuffer import AudioBuffer
```

Why could it not be found?

A picture of the stack trace when trying to import the AudioBuffer module inside a Recorder module

[image]

Edit: removed false assumption/conclusion of the problem
Edit: Added stack trace

Comment: Nope, that's not the reason.  The parens make no difference at all.  You had something else going on.  Is this Python 2 or Python 3?

Comment: Yea seems not the case, the problem came back. It's 3.8

Comment: Show us the whole traceback.  There's information you are not sharing.

Comment: Added a picture. I'm trying to run it by running the python IDLE in the folder and trying to import the module interactively

Comment: That message means that `AudioBuffer.py` is not found.  The environment in an IDLE is different.  You may need `from src.AudioBuffer import AudioBuffer`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you have an empty `__init__.py` file in the directory. Add a dot before the module name:

```
from .AudioBuffer import AudioBuffer
```